# Dart app not showing anything in dartium

Tags: dart, polymer

I'm working on dart app. It was working just fine and suddenly another when I run my dart app from Dart Editor which opens dartium it is not showing anything. I tried to print on console but nothing.

What could be the problem? Any ideas?

One thing I noticed that app is running fine in Chrome with localhost:port but not in dartium browser. I installed the dart support for sublime and even after that everything was fine. Now today when I started dart editor and hit run dartium is not showing anything seems like it is not running.

Comment: Do you get any error in the developer console in Dartium or the output of pub serve? What Dart version are you using? Did you run `pub cache repair`? Did you try to delete the `.pub` directory in your project directory? As a last resort you should try to reinstall Dart.

Comment: They really need to add a proper error message for this, detailing what happened and how to fix it. I had this happen again yesterday, and it still confused me for a bit, even though I've encountered it before.

Comment: This should be fixed since a few weeks. Either they don't expire or they show a hint (don't remember). This expiration is so annoying :(.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I think its expiration issue. I'm updating dart editor and browser. Will update as soon it is done.

Comment: Ok it was indeed an update issue. I updated dart editor including dartium and its now working fine. This link helped me to resolve the issue [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975864/dart-running-a-project-does-not-load-the-dart-file-and-not-printing-in-the-con]